# autoLoginAfterAccountActivation and postLoginRedirect

Tags: config, frontend

Can these things work together? Right now, after verification I am being redirected to the dashboard (/gistApp) instead of being routed through /actions/gistClient/loginControl where I have some user business logic. I know that /actions/gistClient/loginControl works because I can direct navigate to that URL.

Here is my general.php

```
return array(
 'omitScriptNameInUrls' => true,
  'loginPath' => '/gistapp/login',
  'setPasswordSuccessPath' => '/gistapp/login' ,
  'purgePendingUsersDuration' => 'P2M',
  'devMode' => true,
  'autoLoginAfterAccountActivation' => true,
  'postLoginRedirect' => '/actions/gistClient/loginControl',
  'enableCsrfProtection' => true,
  'csrfTokenName' => 'cranberryCsrfToken',
);
```

Comment: Per Brad's answer, this was a bug and has been fixed. Since this question no longer has any historical value, it will be closed as a "bug report".

Answer (score 0):

If the user being registered has access to the control panel, then you'll want to set the [postCpLoginRedirect](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#postCpLoginRedirect) config setting as well.

**Update:**

Looks like this was a bug and the same problem as [this one](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/4305/57).  Should be fixed for the next release.

**Update 2:**

Officially fixed in [2.2 build 2598](http://buildwithcraft.com/updates#build2598).

Comment: No CP access in the case cited above. I am building out an entire frontend experience for these users.

Comment: Ahh... looks like this might be a bug.  Will look into it and update the answer here.

Comment: So, am I correct in assuming that the error is in 'postLoginRedirect' => '/actions/gistClient/loginControl'? I added a redirect to the login form and that works. It does not solve my problem but as a hidden input field the redirect  works.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Is this broken again. I tested this today and after login, was redirected to the homepage. My config settings are the same as above. When I log in through the login form, I am correctly redirected to loginControl. The problem seems to be in chaining autoLoginAfterAccountActivation and postLoginRedirect